# State Pattern Design using OOP

Tags: c++, switch-statement, state

A simple example of how you would structure this would be particularly useful.

Comment: `Please provide coded examples` This site is not meant to be free homework completion service.

Comment: @Ben This is not homework.

Comment: Use a state table.  No need for the overhead of OOP.

Comment: @Ben, I wasn't asking you to write the code for me. Just provide a simple example demonstrating how you would go about doing this. Perhaps you could just point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

`MyMotor` is an instance of the class `Motor`. This class has four functions `idle()`, `accelerate()`, `flat()`, `decelerate()`. (I assume you know how to build a basic class with private members and its constructors)

Then in `main()`, I create `MyMotor` and control it based on states. States can be controlled/monitored using Boolean Values. Whatever state I am in and whenever, certain function will be called.

Next time give it a try before you ask here, in order to get better responses.